# SQL Server. Do the insered and deleted tables have default columns?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, dml

Apologies if this has already been answered. I've trawled through a bunch of similar ones and can't find the answer.

The inserted and deleted columns contain all the columns of the table you're inserting / updating / deleting.

What I want to know is do they **ONLY** contain the columns that are present in the table that's getting it's data amended, or do they have any ***additional*** columns that SQL server generates by default?

Cheers

Ian

Comment: The `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo tables only contain columns from the target table.

Comment: [Use the inserted and deleted Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: They have exactly the column(s) in the updated table. You could easily verify by creating a simple trigger containing `select * from inserted`. Or just read the documentation.

Comment: I would suggest just share what exactly query you have written and your table structure  for proper answer.